# how to find anything but an expression in regex?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find a paragraph that start with a word "a" or word "b" and finish with them ( but they are not included in the end), i found a regex that do that but the issue is that the text that are between those two conditions shouldn't match multiples dots and followed by a number. something like this : "......... 889"
i tried something like this

```
(a|b)(?!([.]+[0-9]+))(?=(a|b))
```

a or b followed by anything but multiple dots and a number and a or b that are not included

if i give an input like this

```
a xxx 
................... 899
xxx
b
xxx
a
```

i should get

```
b
xxx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match either a or b followed by all lines that do not start with either a or b or with multiple dots and a digit.

Then you could assert that the next line does start with either a or b.

Note that there is a space after the last dot and the digit.

```
[ab]\b(?!\.+\s*\d).*(?:\r?\n(?![ab]|.*\.+\s*\d).*)*(?=\r?\n[ab]\b)
```

The pattern matches

- `[ab]\b` Match a or b
- `(?!\.+\s*\d).*` Check that it is not followed by dots and a digit
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\r?\n(?![ab]|.*\.+\s*\d).*` Match the whole line if it does not start with a or b or dots followed by a digit
- `)*` Close the group and optionally repeat it to match all lines
- `(?=\r?\n[ab]\b)` Check for a or b on the next line

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AJsQRA/1)

Or shorter if there is a newline right after a or b

```
^[ab](?:\r?\n(?![ab]$|.*\.+\s*\d).*)*(?=\r?\n[ab]$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/X5DuCe/1)